# Разбиение строк в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Есть файл такого содержания (список работающих сервисов tomcat):

```
running:courtjudgementclaimcardws-ws-1.0
running:courtofficerws-ws-1.0
running:usk62ws-ws-1.0
running:destinationscopiesresultingdocumentws-ws-1.0
stopped:categoriescrimeguidews-ws-1.0
running:crimeepisodecardws-ws-1.0
running:documentmodulews-ws-1.0
```

Как средствами bash получить из этих строк два массива по разделителю `:`?

Comment: да как и обычно: `m1=( ... ); m2=( ... )`. конкретизируйте трудности, с которыми столкнулись.

Comment: `echo bla-bla:qwer | cut -d ':' -f 2`?

Comment: Я небольшой специалист по shell. Что означает "да как и обычно: m1=( ... ); m2=( ... )"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вам нужно получить отдельные файлы с содержимым каждого из полей разделенных **":"** тогда так

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1}' source_file >> destination_file_1 && \
awk -F ":" '{print $2}' source_file >> destination_file_2
```

Если Вам нужно получить массивы в переменные, то тогда так

```
a=( $( awk -F ":" '{print $1}' source_file ) ) && \
b=( $( awk -F ":" '{print $2}' source_file ) )
```

**UPD**
Более корректное решение выглядит так:

```
mapfile -t a <<<"$(awk -F ":" '{print $1}' source_file)"
```

Поскольку если в выводе встретятся строки содержащие пробелы то первый вариант запишет их в отдельные строки массива разделив по пробелу.

В случае если Вам нужно получить массивы с согласованной нумерацией строк, то можно использовать следующее решение:

```
awk -F ":" '{print $1}' source_file | \
awk '{printf "%s-%s\n", NR, $0}' > destination_file_1

awk -F ":" '{print $2}' source_file | \
awk '{printf "%s-%s\n", NR, $0}' > destination_file_2
```

Между %s и %s можно вставить любой резделитель
В переменные эти массивы загоняются так-же как и во втором примере.

**UPD**
Менее громоздкий вариант:

```
awk -F ':' '{printf " %s-%s\n, NR, $1}' source_file > destination_file_1 && \
awk -F ':' '{printf " %s-%s\n, NR, $2}' source_file > destination_file_2
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил так:

```
index=0

while IFS= read line
do
    IFS=":" read status service <<< "$line"
    STATUS[$index]="$status"
    SERVICE[$index]="$service"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < temp.txt
```

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет более короткое решение

Comment: `$ declare -a a b; i=0; while IFS=: read a[i] b[i++]; do :; done < <(echo -e '1:2\n3:4'); echo "a=${a[@]} b=${b[@]}"`